# why can't I create a here-string in Powershell ISE?

Tags: powershell, herestring

Trying to create a here-string

```
> $scriptblock =@'
The string is missing the terminator: '@.
 + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Why am I getting this in the Powershell ISE, but it works normally in Powershell?
Version 5.1.

```
> $scriptblock =@'
>>
```

No, there's no space after the single-quote. I just hit enter.
I even closed and reopened ISE and same thing.

Comment: Press `[Shift+Enter]` to insert a literal newline in the ISE console

Comment: Yes or use the integrated scripting pane

Comment: I had to go into full screen with my Remote Desktop application for that to work so that it wouldn't capture that key combination. Why did I not know about that? Not very convenient, Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Mathias R. Jessen:
Press [Shift+Enter] to insert a literal newline in the ISE console